# Xray and distracting geometry

Tags: topology

I want to retopo an object so I tried using the Xray option to make my new mesh appear in the viewport in front of others. However I don't want to be able to see on my new mesh faces that are facing away from the camera or are behind other faces as it's making the process pretty hard. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the feature I was looking for wasn't actually X-ray or at least there's another workaround. Instead I used the shrinkwrap modifier with a little bit of positive offset so that the new mesh doesn't sink into the original one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called 'Hidden Wire' which I think might do what you are talking about. When you are in edit mode the option will appear in the 'Properties' toolbar in the 3D view (<kbd>N</kbd>) in the 'Shading' panel:

[image]

This will change the object into a wireframe shaded mode (so make sure you turn off any other wire/x-ray properties you may have turned on for that object) but will occlude faces behind the object.

Here I have turend on 'Hidden Wire' while in edit mode of a sphere. The sphere has turned to wire so I can see the object within it, but I can't see the other side of the sphere:

[image]

Comment: Hidden wire simply hides the faces but I don't mind them showing up. It doesn't also fix the sinking part. Perhaps the original question wasn't clear enough as I wasn't even sure what I was looking for. I wanted that the retopo mesh appears on top of the original one without interacting with its surface with the exception that the back facing parts should be hidden. Something like topogun: http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/239/5/0/humphrey_davis_topo_fix_in_topogun_by_wachak-d5cm4du.jpg

Comment: Ah, then I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you're asking as even what you described in the comment sounds like what hidden wire is. Perhaps my answer wasn't clear in the fact that the sphere, even though it is higher res, is in fact the equivalent of the retopo object.